# Call for a python script from a PBS job

Tags: python, bash, delay, pbs, qsub

How can I call a python script to run from a pbs job?
Some more details: 
I am currently working with a pbs file of the following shape (this part works perfectly and shouldn't be altered):

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -N # work name 
#PBS -q 
#PBS -l 
#PBS -S /bin/bash
#PBS -m 
##PBS -M #my email 
cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
```

I have to modify it so after the calculation above finishes a python script (which works on the output file) will be called. 
The calculation takes a few minutes to finish so a delay before the calling for the python script has to be specified. I have no knowledge in bash programming so it's a real struggle for me.

Answer (score 4):

You just have to add the lines to call the python script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -N # work name 
#PBS -q 
#PBS -l 
#PBS -S /bin/bash
#PBS -m 
##PBS -M #my email 
cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
python3 my_python_script.py
```